# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I am getting a parsing exception while I am trying the following code:

```
    String date="Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date currentdate;
    currentdate=sdf.parse(date);
    System.out.println(currentdate);
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013"
>   at com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:510)

Input: `Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013`

Expected output: `Jun 01,2013 12:53:10`

How to solve this?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Your pattern does not correspond to the input string at all... It is not surprising that it does not work. This would probably work better:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                            Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Then to print with your required format you need a second SimpleDateFormat:

```
Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(print.format(parsedDate));
```

Notes:

- you should include the locale as if your locale is not English, the day name might not be recognised
- [IST is ambiguous and can lead to problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264697/java-timezone-strange-behavior-with-ist) so you should use the proper time zone name if possible in your input.

Comment: I got the same exception for the following date :October 24, 2013   with the following *correct* format:  "MMMMM dd, yyyy" . Only when I specified the Locale.ENGLISH as you mentioned, the problem solved. tnx

Comment: @assylias How to include the timezone here.Please help me.

Comment: @KJEjava48 It depends on what format you want - it's all explained in the javadoc of SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: what if IST is returned from an API? its always going to be sent back to me in that format?

Comment: Use both of the code lines together, but first define at the beginning the object like R.id.object e.t.c.

Answer (score 8):

```
        String date="Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Date currentdate=sdf.parse(date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(sdf2.format(currentdate));
```

Answer (score 6):

Pattern is wrong

```
    String date="Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    Date currentdate;
    currentdate=sdf.parse(date);
    System.out.println(currentdate);
```

Answer (score 4):

- Your formatting pattern fails to match the input string, as noted by other Answers.
- Your input format is *terrible*.
- You are using troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

## ISO 8601

Instead a format such as yours, use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for exchanging date-time values as text.

The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

### Proper time zone name

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Your `IST` could mean *Iceland Standard Time*, *India Standard Time*, *Ireland Standard Time*, or others. The *java.time* classes are left to merely guessing, as there is no logical solution to this ambiguity.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input strings.

```
String input = "Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2013-06-01T12:53:10Z[Atlantic/Reykjavik]

If your input was not intended for Iceland, you should pre-parse the string to adjust to a proper time zone name. For example, if you are certain the input was intended for India, change `IST` to `Asia/Kolkata`.

```
String input = "Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013".replace( "IST" , "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2013-06-01T12:53:10+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3):

Update your format to:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

I found simple solution to get current date without any parsing error.

```
Calendar calendar;
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String customDate = "" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String date="Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013";

SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

This patterns **does not tally** with your **input String** which occurs the **exception**.

You need to use following **pattern** to get the work done.

```
E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

Following code will help you to **skip the exception**.

`SimpleDateFormat` is **used**.

```
    String date="Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013"; // Input String

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"); // Existing Pattern

    Date currentdate=simpleDateFormat.parse(date); // Returns Date Format,

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // New Pattern

    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat1.format(currentdate)); // Format given String to new pattern

    // outputs: Jun 01,2013 12:53:10
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your Pattern (DD-MMM-YYYY) and the input for the parse("29-11-2018") method.
Input to the parse method should follow : DD-MMM-YYYY i,e. 21-AUG-2019

In My Code:

```
String pattern = "DD-MMM-YYYY";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

    try {
        startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("29-11-2018");// here no pattern match 
        endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("28-AUG-2019");// Ok 
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Wrong. I first got `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28-AUG-2019"`. When supplying `Locale.ENGLISH` to the formatter I instead got `Sun Dec 30 00:00:00 CET 2018` — pretty far from the expected. Also when this question was asked in 2013, it was reasonable to use `SimpleDateFormat`, but not today, it’s poorly designed and long outdated. Use java.time as shown in the answer by Basil Bourque. Finally it seems you’re not answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is in bad format to the input String. It can be easily solved:

```
//init SimpleDateFormat as pattern & Locale parameter
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault());

//parse with your date
Date dateParser = dateFormat.parse(dayOfMonth + "." + (month) + "." + year);
```

Then you can easily change pattern of SimpleDateFormat (depend if you have Locale parameter)

```
dateFormat.applyLocalizedPattern("dd MMM, yyyy");
```

To cast to String:

```
dateObject.setText(dateFormat.format(dateParser));
```

Answer (score -1):

I needed to add a `ParsePosition` expression to the parse method of class `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
simpledateformat.parse(mydatestring, new ParsePosition(0));
```