# How to convert String to date using Java in UNIX environment

Tags: java, date, unix, date-conversion

I am trying to convert a String ("01-OCT-2014") into Date format.

Below is my code for this.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date d= formatter.parse("01-OCT-2014");
System.out.println("Converted date:"+d);
```

The above code is working fine in Windows.

But when I am running in Unix environment, it is throwing an exception **Unparseable date**

Can any one help me out in solving this issue..

Comment: check it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16871410/2591002

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is simply that your Unix environment isn't running in an English locale - so when it tries to parse the month name, it's not recognizing "OCT" as a valid value.

I would suggest using code like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
Date d = formatter.parse("01-OCT-2014");
System.out.println("Converted date: " + d);
```

You might also want to specify the time zone of the formatter - if you're just parsing a date, then using UTC would make sense. Note that your output will use the system local time zone, because you're using `Date.toString()` - that *doesn't* mean that the `Date` has any notion of the time zone in its data; a `Date` is just a point in time.