# converting a string to date in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TesterA
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

        try
        {
            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to run this sample code copy from a web, but it doesn't work. How should I change it?

This is the error I got

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "7-Jun-2013"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at TesterA.main(TesterA.java:14)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

Comment: The code would work fine with JDK 7. Do you run under java 6?

Comment: I run it under JDK 8, and now after I add the locale, it works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871367/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.text.ParseException` means you provided a string which cannot be parsed using the current settings.

Just set the [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a problem with your locale.

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: @petersze I have run your code and it works on my computer with locale german. If i change to france for instance I get the same error as you