# Unparseable date exception while converting UTC time

Tags: java, date, parseexception

So there is my problem- 
i am using this format to convert my string into a date :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy", Locale.US);
```

and there is the code that i am trying to convert with him ("s" is an object of mine , and setBirthday is function that initialize my date variable):

```
 s.setbirthday(dateFormat.parse(myDateString));
```

myDateString(the one i want convert to date ) has the next value (which is String) : -"Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 UTC 1913 " .

So any time i a trying to run the program i am getting this exception :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 UTC 1913"
```

I looked on other threads here but no one helped me so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't mix timezone chars - remove the `Z`

Comment: @Reimeus is right. If you change your SimpleDateFormat pattern to SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US) it works perfectly.

Comment: strill not working ... :(

Comment: Works for me. Please give all the code  - from beginning to end

Comment: try changing the format string to this: "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871367/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date)

Comment: @Basil Bourque It's not a duplicate. His pattern is valid.

Comment: @mwarren Looks like a dup to me, with incorrect use of `z` and `Z`. A dup of dozens if not hundreds of other Questions and Answers as well. Unnecessarily posted here, if Tal had bothered to read any of those many others.