# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11:00 PM, Sun 07 Oct 2018"

Tags: java

I have tried the code below, but it's not working.

Please explain why it's not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ti = "11:30 PM, Sun 07 Oct 2018";
    String sformat = "h:m a, E dd M yyyy";
    String cformat = "hh:mm a";
    String d = dateFormater(ti, cformat, sformat);
    System.out.println(d);
}

public static String dateFormater(String dateFromJSON,
                                  String expectedFormat, String oldFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
    Date date = null;
    String convertedDate = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(dateFromJSON);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedFormat);
        convertedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertedDate;
}
```

Comment: Please define "it's not working". Is it crashing? It does not produce the desired output? If yes, what is the expected output and the current output?

Comment: its output is giving an exception (java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11:30 PM, Sun 07 Oct 2018");

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871367/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern needs

- `MMM` because the month is in short litteral format (`M` only is for month number and `MMMM` is for long litteral format)

  ```
  String sformat = "h:m a, E dd MMM yyyy";
  ```

---

And you should consider using new `time` API : `java.time` as it's easier to use and don't need extra mandatory `try/catch` :

```
public static String dateFormater(String dateFromJSON, String expectedFormat, String oldFormat) {
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFromJSON, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(oldFormat, Locale.ENGLISH));
    String newStr = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(expectedFormat, Locale.ENGLISH));
    return newStr;
}
```

or in a single-line :

```
public static String dateFormaterSh(String dateFromJSON, String expectedFormat, String oldFormat) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(dateFromJSON, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(oldFormat, Locale.ENGLISH))
                        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(expectedFormat, Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is incorrect. Please use the format below.

```
String sformat= "hh:mm a, EEE dd MMM yyyy";
```

Comment: @Rik Please accept the answer (By clicking on the tick mark near my answer) if this solves your problem.

Comment: It's not clear that "hh" is correct here - we can't tell based on the input. It's relatively rare to have a zero-padded hour of day *and* an AM/PM indicator.

Comment: thank you,problem was solved but there wasn't any  pinpointing explanation.