# Unparseable Date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, date

I stored a `MySQL` `DATE` (from a web service) in a `SQLite` `TEXT`.

I'm no expert when working with dates, so as I was searching, I found you parse the date string into a `java.util.Date`.

This were my results:

```
// Works like a charm    
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(strdate)

// Unparseable date exception
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(strdate);
```

Could I get some directions on this please?

Comment: What is the value of `strdate`? Post the exception stack trace.

Comment: reply your strdate value ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instructing the date parser that your input `strdate` is in format `dd-MMM-yyyy`. But actually it is in `EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy` format.

```
+----------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+
| date pattern you tried     | your strdate input           | pattern  | parse  |
|                            |                              | matched? | error? |
+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------+--------+
| EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy | Fri Apr 04 06:55:24 GMT 2014 | yes      | no     |
+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------+--------+
| dd-MMM-yyyy                | Fri Apr 04 06:55:24 GMT 2014 | no       | yes    |
+----------------------------+------------------------------+----------+--------+
```

If you are trying to re format the same date string for display purposes, then

1. construct a date object first with its default format received
2. apply new pattern to return a string form of the same date.

**Example**:

```
String strdate = "Fri Apr 04 06:55:24 GMT 2014";  
String currentPattern = "EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy";  
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( currentPattern, Locale.ENGLISH );

Date dt = sdf.parse( strdate ); // new date is constructed
System.out.println( dt );

String newPattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";     // new pattern is defined  
sdf.applyPattern( newPattern );        // the same is applied
String new_strdate = sdf.format( dt ); // on the date object
System.out.println( new_strdate );     // resulting new string form of date
```

**Output** would be as below:

```
Fri Apr 04 06:55:24 GMT 2014
04-Apr-2014
```

Comment: Now I'm not getting an exception, but the `new_strdate` needs to be in a `Date` object, but when I do again `SimpleDateFormat`, it goes back to the previous format

Answer (score 1):

***try this:***

***Then to print with your required format you need a second SimpleDateFormat: sample code***

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                        Locale.ENGLISH);

Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(print.format(parsedDate));
```

***Notes:***

1. *you should include the locale as if your locale is not English, the
   day name might not be recognised.*
2. *IST is ambiguous and can lead to problems so you should use the
   proper time zone name if possible in your input.*

[Java timezone - strange behavior with IST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264697/java-timezone-strange-behavior-with-ist)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

Answer (score 1):

You can parse by this way,

#### Android

```
    Date yourdate = format.parse(strdate);
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(yourdate);
    System.out.println("dd-MMM-yyyy format : " + date);
```

#### Result

```
    dd-MMM-yyyy format : 04-Apr-2014
```

Answer (score 1):

`parse`  expects Date String in the format you have specified in    `SimpleDateFormat` constructor. check the date stored in SQLite, it might be in "EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy"  format