# SimpleDateFormat - Unparsable Date exception with IST timezone. What's wrong?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have string with date in that format:

```
Oct 28, 2015, 05.15PM IST
```

So I want to parse it to Date object using SimpleDateFormat:

```
String date = "Oct 28, 2015, 05.15PM IST";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mmaa zzz", Locale.US);
Date myDate = format.parse(date);
```

But I get exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Oct 28, 2015, 05.15PM IST" (at offset 22)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the given code, It works [here](http://ideone.com/m9A6LL)

Comment: @sam I'm confused. In my code it still trows an exception.

Comment: Check [Java: unparseable date exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009207/java-unparseable-date-exception). It is a similar question

Comment: @sam Okay, seems like I don't have "IST" id. But how can I deal with it so?

Comment: This is caused by ambiguity in the timezone 'IST'. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264697/java-timezone-strange-behavior-with-ist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that SimpleDateFormat can't parse "IST" as timezone because it ambiguous.

I solved that problem according to  [Adriaan Koster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800198/3809678).
But actually it worked for me only after I cutted " IST" from my date string.
So complete solution for the problem looks like that:

```
String date = "Oct 28, 2015, 05.15PM IST";
date = date.substring(0, date.length()-4);

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mma", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
Date myDate = format.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the `SimpleDateFormat`when specifying the AM/PM component, you need not use two a's nor three z's. You are trying to parse "Oct 28, 2015, 05.15PM IST" with more than one AM/PM specifier, as well as more than one timezone specifier. Change your format Object to `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, hh.mma z", Locale.US);`