# Set timezone to IST, but I still get a wrong-date error

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date

I want to take current time irrespective to the system date. I am using Glassfish server and derby in netbeans. I tried the code below for getting current date according to IST:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("ist"));
    String gmtTime = df.format(new java.util.Date().getTime());

    java.util.Date parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = (java.util.Date) df.parse(gmtTime);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EmployeePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
```

but I am getting 2017-01-08 instead of 2017-08-08.

Comment: Apart from Jens' answer, check this question too -> [Java timezone - strange behavior with IST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264697/java-timezone-strange-behavior-with-ist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m is minute not month (M). The right pattern is:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
```

The pattern definition is case sensitive!

For more informations see [the javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)